# Textarea appears outside table

Tags: html, html-table

I have a table with two table rows. I want a textarea with full width in the second row. When I use `<td></td>` around the textarea, I cannot get it to full width. But if I remove them, I can, but the textarea comes above the table. Why does it do that? Is it required to have the `<td></td>` tags?

```html
<table name='table1'>
  <tr>
    <td><input type='text' name='input1' placeholder='input1'></td>
    <td><input type='text' name='input2' placeholder='input2' required></td>
    <td><input type='text' name='input3' placeholder='input3' required></td>
    <td><input type='text' name='input4' placeholder='input4' required></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <textarea id='text' name='text' rows='30' placeholder='Message'></textarea>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Solution: added `<td colspan="4"></td>` around the textarea. Someone commented it, but it was removed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use it like this to make it as full width

```
<table name='table1'>
    <tr>
     <td><input type='text' name='input1' placeholder='input1'></td>
     <td><input type='text' name='input2' placeholder='input2' required></td>
     <td><input type='text' name='input3' placeholder='input3' required></td>
     <td><input type='text' name='input4' placeholder='input4' required></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
       <td colspan="4">
            <textarea id='text' name='text' rows='30' placeholder='Message' style="width: 100%;"></textarea>
       </td>
   </tr>
 </table>
```